# List Index Out of Range when accessing row read from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I am trying to read a csv file in python. The csv file has 1400 rows. I opened the csv file using the following command:

```
import csv  
import sys             
f=csv.reader(open("/Users/Brian/Desktop/timesheets_9_1to10_5small.csv","rU"),
    dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```

Then I tried to loop through the file to pull the first name from each row using the following commmands:

```
for row in f:
    g=row
    s=g[0]  
    end_of_first_name=s.find(",")
    first_name=s[0:end_of_first_name]
```

I got the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 3, in module
>      s=g[0]
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Does anyone know why I would get this error message and how I can correct it?

Comment: Did you try adding `print row` inside the loop to see what it thinks the rows are?  One of them (maybe at the end) is empty.  Incidentally, I don't understand your `end_of_first_name` logic (unless, as it's just occurred to me, there are multiple names there, and by "First" you don't mean "John" in "John Smith", you mean "John" in "John, Fred".)

Comment: I bet if you did len(g) it would return 0.  It sounds like you have an empty row.

Comment: good idea. I added a print row and realized that the code is having trouble with a row deep in the csv file. I will try to find out why that row is troublesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You should *not* open the file in universal newline mode (`U`). Open the file in binary mode instead:

```
f=csv.reader(open("/Users/Brian/Desktop/timesheets_9_1to10_5small.csv","rb"),
    dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```

CSV does it's *own* newline handling, including managing newlines in quotes.

Next, print your rows with `print repr(row)` to verify that you are getting the output you are expecting. Using `repr` instead of the regular string representation shows you much more about the *type* of objects you are handling, highlighting such differences as strings versus integers (`'1'` vs. `1`).

Thirdly, if you want to select part of a string up to a delimiter such as a comma, use [`.split(delimiter, 1)`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) or [`.partition(delimiter)[0]`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> 'John,Jack,Jill'.partition(',')[0]
'John'
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. I tried to open it in binary mode (rb) and got the following error message
Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode? I used the print repr(row) technique and realized that the code is having trouble on a row deep in the csv file. I will try to find out why that row is troublesome. thank you!

Comment: @user1744871: Right, there appears to be a bug in the csv module; see [Python and csv help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2930673) Glad my `repr()` trick helped you.

Answer (score 0):

row and g point to an empty list. I don't know if that necessarily means that it is empty line in the file as csv may have other issues with it.

```
line_counter = 0
for row in f:
    line_counter = line_counter + 1
    g=row
    if len(g) == 0:
        print "line",line_counter,"may be empty or malformed"
        continue
```

Or, as Martijn points out, the Pythonic way is using enumerate:

```
for line_counter, row in enumerate(f,start=1):
    g=row
    if len(g) == 0:
        print "line",line_counter,"may be empty or malformed"
        continue
```

Comment: Use `for line_counter, row in enumerate(f):` instead of an explicit counter.

Comment: this is a great way to deal with the break condition. thank you for responding.